# Sublime Text and Python 3 open a Terminal in mac when build

Tags: python-3.x, macos, sublimetext3

How can I in mac execute python 3 in Sublime Text and it open terminal window running script?

I want write script in sublime Text but running like I execute from terminal

I saw a lot of tutorial but  they run script in sublime text.